# Opening multiple new tabs in Chrome with Undetected-Chromedriver through Python

Tags: python-3.x, undetected-chromedriver

I want to open multiple new tabs one after another with different URLs **in the same Chrome window** by importing Undetected-Chromedriver library of Python (no use of Selenium).

Can someone help how to structure the below code?

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
driver = uc.Chrome()
url1 = https://www.google.com
url2 = https://www.facebook.com

>> open url1 in first tab in chrome
>> then open url2 in second tab of the same chrome window
```